# select columns for query object returned by a scope method in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to create scope method like ruby on rails and select columns for the result of the scope method as follows:

```
class PersonModel(object):

   def __init__(self, session):
       self.session = session

   def male_scope(self):
       query = self.session.query(Person).filter(Person.sex == 'male')
       return query

   def get_male_ids(self):
       results = self.male_scope().query(Person.id).all() #=> this is not correct
       return results
```

but cannot call query() twice and got error:

```
person = PersonModel(session)
male_ids = person.get_male_ids()
```

`AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'query'`

any ways to select columns for the result of scope method?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the list of things queried by using [`.with_entities()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities):

```
self.male_scope().with_entities(Person.id)
```

Comment: That's exactly what i want!! Thanks a lot!!